# Proguard strips custom annotations in Kotlin

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, kotlin

My Kotlin project uses MVP architecture. Custom annotations are being used to the bins presenter to the view for example:

```
@PresenterBinding(MyPresenter::class)
class MyActivity{
```

When this project is build with Proguard's

```
minifyEnabled true
```

The link of presenter to the view is lost and I get `kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException` accessing presenter functions

Following bits are there in my Proguard config (among other keep rules)

```
# Kotlin rules #
-assumenosideeffects class kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics {
    static void checkParameterIsNotNull(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String);
}
-keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {
    <fields>;
}
-dontwarn kotlin.**
-keep class kotlin.**

-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

I have tried many things, however no luck yet.
Any pointers to the right are welcome.

Comment: did you find a workaround? I'm having the same problem, Proguard strips annotations and even visibility/nullability info...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565633/

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: In the meantime I did :) check the question I linked if you're interested.