# Kotlin: ProGuard erases properties attributes

Tags: android, proguard, kotlin

**TL;DR**: with proguard enabled, when using reflection, my properties look private, non-nullable and without annotations, despite proguard config that should keep all these attributes.

I have some simple `data class`es with public properties to serve as data models in my Android app. Later, when doing generic [de]serialization of said classes, I filter the property list like this:

```
val properties = instance::class.memberProperties
        .filter { it.visibility == KVisibility.PUBLIC } // && some other conditions, unrelated here
        .filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>()
```

It works normally on my debug builds (I mean it selects the properties I want it to). But, when doing a **release** build, where proguard is active, **the result is empty**. To check why, I logged all the relevant stuff about the properties of one class -- turns out their `visibility` field reads `PRIVATE` (and all other attributes remain the same as on a debug build).

I already have a line in proguard config to keep all the models:

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.models.package.name.BaseModel { *; }
```

I tried this one before, with same result:

```
-keep class com.models.package.name.** { *; }
```

Why/how does proguard affect property visibility? Should I modify the config somehow? Or am I missing something else here?

---

**UPDATE**: It seems like visibility is not the only thing. `prop.returnType.isMarkedNullable` also doesn't work, it returns `false` for properties declared nullable. And annotations also seem to get lost, even though I asked proguard to keep them. Is there any way to work around this? It pretty much renders 2 weeks of my work useless...

Comment: The information being lost is stored in @KotlinMetadata annotations. You need to make sure that your ProGuard config does not delete those annotations.

Comment: @yole I have in my proguard config: `-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature,InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod`. So no annotations should be deleted at all. And with the `-keep` commands for my model classes, they shouldn't be stripped at all, should they? Maybe do you know of any proguard trick to make it so?

Comment: I personally don't have much experience with proguard. You can use javap on the .class files after proguard to make sure the annotation is there.

Comment: actually, you suggested the right thing to do! I had to tell proguard to `-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }` and all the details are there! Thanks! It's really weird that it's not enough to tell it to keep my models intact though.

If you want to post this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from @yole in question comments, I've been able to make this work. Even though my classes were configured to be kept by ProGuard, it stripped the `kotlin.Metadata` annotations from them. These annotatons are where Kotlin stores all the attributes I was missing. The solution is to prevent ProGuard from deleting them, adding to configuration:

```
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
```

(on a side note: it's weird that it's not included in the default config, at least if you're using the `kotlin.reflect.full` package. Or at least it should be mentioned clearly somewhere in the docs...)